# Regular Expression to match prefix

Tags: .net, regex

Initially I had this following question:

Add multiple GroupName in textbox.

1. The GroupName can be separated by `","` / `"or"` / `"OR"`.
2. Input should not start with or end with `","` / `"or"` / `"OR"`.

eg:

```
GroupName, GroupName or GroupName OR GroupName 
GroupName, GroupName, GroupName, GroupName or GroupName
```

For this i found the answer as

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?:\s*(?:or|OR|,)\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)*$/
```

How to modify this reqular expression to support `or` `OR` keywords as prefix. Also there cannot be two consecutive prefix, eg:

```
or or GroupName
```

(Above example is not valid input.)

Can anyone help me out in this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) and then simplify it so your pattern is only the tokens?

So you would say something like

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, "[\w]?(OR|,)[\w]?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then just discard the empty substrings rather than worrying about preventing empty items. This approach, incidentally, will pull out the delimiter into the result array because they are a capture group, but the linked documentation shows how to avoid that.

Also, because it ignores whitespace it might pull out a result like "Oregon" as "OR" and "Egon" so you might want to force whitespace matches for the "Or" operator, although I would avoid it for "," as people may well use that without spaces.